# Lie group commutator bound $|[g,h]|< C|g||h|$

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, normed-spaces, smooth-manifolds

So I'm reading a paper and I don't understand why this property holds. Namely, suppose we have a Lie Group $G$ and define a smooth norm on it, take $|g|=d(g,1)$ for example, then for sufficiently small neighborhood around $1$, any elements $g,h$ in that neighborhood satisfy $|[g,h]|< C|g||h|$ for some constant $C$. Can someone explain the details why this is true.

Comment: I think it's somehow because $(g,h)\mapsto [g,h]$ is continuous (w.r.t. the norm).

Comment: It seems that $|[g,h]|=|ghg^{-1}h^{-1}|$ is of fourth order, while $|g|\cdot|h|$ is of second order, thus is asymptotically greater than the former.

Comment: @Berci that's what I thought at first, but I wasn't able to see why it leads to the given inequality.

Comment: Hint: Use Taylor's theorem from the multivariable calculus (but first show that the derivative of the commutator map is zero at the origin).

Comment: @Moishe Why can we even apply Taylor's theorem here? Smoothness doesn't give us analyticity, necessarily. Also if it were true how would you compute it from an arbitrary chart? The commutator isn't guaranteed to be in the same neighborhood as the identity.

Comment: Taylor's theorem is not about analytic functions, although this is how it is frequently used, it is about an error estimate for the Taylor polynomial approximation.